# Authority "AUTO" is unknown or doesn't match the supplied hints. Maybe it is defined in an unreachable JAR file?

Tags: mysql, coordinate-systems, geotools

I am working on a project related to Coordinate Reference Systems (CRS) using geoTools. I am getting 'NoSuchAuthorityCodeException' exception with the above message while executing my jar. Things work fine when using EPSG CRS Authority. Fails when I specify 'AUTO:42001' CRSAuthorityFactory. Is there any Library/plug-in to be used. ?

Below is the Exception

> at
>   org.geotools.referencing.factory.ManyAuthoritiesFactory.noSuchAuthority(ManyAuthoritiesFactory.java:489)
>           at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ManyAuthoritiesFactory.getAuthorityFactory(ManyAuthoritiesFactory.java:467)
>           at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ManyAuthoritiesFactory.getCRSAuthorityFactory(ManyAuthoritiesFactory.java:548)
>           at org.geotools.referencing.factory.AuthorityFactoryAdapter.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(AuthorityFactoryAdapter.java:801)
>           at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ThreadedAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(ThreadedAuthorityFactory.java:731)
>           at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:179)
>           at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:519)

Comment: Are you including one of the gt-epsg jars?  If so, which one?  More details are here: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/faq.html.

Comment: Hi I have included gt-epsg-hsql jar version 10.8.  In the link provided it is mentioned that "The main module includes definitions of AUTO and AUTO2 and several other OGC inspired ideas". What is this main module.

Comment: And also please me know where I can find this main module jar.

Comment: are you building a super-jar? if so you need to use the maven shade plugin - see http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/build/faq.html

Comment: Yes, i tried using maven shade plugin, but no luck :(

Comment: Is it something related to Hints of CRS or maybe a system evnm variable the jars tries to access ?